# iOS 10 upgrade causing keydown event errors with bluetooth scanner

Tags: jquery, ios, iphone, bluetooth, event-handling

Our shop has a scanner device for its web app where we handle the input of the device using jQuery keydown event. This has been working fine except now all older iPhones (4,5,6) seem to have problems with handling the keydown event upon upgrade. What I notice is the + sign and then the enter key is triggered almost simultaneously but most browsers handle this properly...

The processing is triggered when the user hits the ENTER key or the Scanner hits the + key ie:

```
e.which = 13 || e.which = 187
```

When I step through the SAFARI debugger the value of the jQuery selector is empty. When the val() of the selector has the actual scanned UPC barcode the iPhone passes the keydown events and the hotkey iOS keyboard is triggered. Since we have it setup for focusout to trigger processing as well the user can hit done on his/her iPhone and put focus back into the selector and scan the next item.

This is hardly a viable solution as our users need to be able to scan continuously on their iPhones. Any suggestions?

Here is a snippet of the code:

```
$("input[name='SCAN']").on("keydown",function(e) {
         var processRegex = /^([0-9]{7,14}\+?)$/;
        //on SCAN (last character is a '+/=') field - reload detail section
         if (e.which == 13 || e.which == 187){
                scan_val = $.trim($("[name='SCAN']").val());
                if(processRegex.test(scan_val)){               
                  Handle_Scan(scan_val); //ajax processing function         
                }
                else
                    $("[name='SCAN']").val('').focus();

            return false;
        }

            return true;
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its as if the DOM element's value passes the regX but the keydown eventListener passes the value back prematurely as if it hasn't caught up to the last key capture possibly giving reference to the wrong memory address. This was not a problem until the iOS 10 upgrades! I wonder how this javascript engine differs from previous versions?

I had to wrap the entire processing logic with a `setTimeout(function(){ //handle_scan},250);` in order to allow the event handler to finish capturing the last `keydown` event and give control back to the DOM so the caller could then execute the function.

Clearly this shouldn't happen. So what is so confusing to me is that it seems like the javascript engine is either too fast or the event listener is too slow.

I thought it may have something to do with using `keydown` instead of `keyup` since you can continuously fire the event handler by holding the key down since the scanner performs this action in a split milisecond but it did not matter which handler I used. I went with `keydown` thinking that would give control back to the caller faster hoping the workaround wouldn't be needed.

Maybe the javascript engine reads the value while the event listener is polling for the next hardware interrupt?